# Missing menu bar on Cinnamon desktop on CentOS 7. Where are the Cinnamon settings located in CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, linux-mint, cinnamon, desktop

I got Cinnamon 3.6.7 on my newly installed CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core).  The menu bar on the bottom is missing and I have been failing to find a solution on Google. I haven't even found where the Cinnamon settings are located on CentOS 7. I have tried right-clicking everywhere but it doesn't go to the menu bar settings. (I could only find the settings to change the background picture.)

Here is what my desktop looks like:

[image: Cinnamon on Centos 7 without menu bar]

The menu bar pops up on the left side if I slide my mouse to the top left corner. **I wish to move the menu bar to the bottom and pin it there with icons of common applications also pinned.**

[image: Cinnamon menu bar on the left side]

(I followed [these instructions](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-install-cinnamon-gui-in-centos-7-linux/) to install Cinnamon on CentOS.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't actually booted into `cinnamon`, you're still using the default `gnome` desktop environment.

If you log out, then go to log back in, you'll see a little cog icon next to the "sign in" button. Click that, and select `cinnamon` as per the below:

[image: cinnamon login]

Then login, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

This *response* may not be on point.  I **manually** combine Cinnamon with Fedora, rather than using a spin. I found a curious anomaly.

1. After a complete re-install of Fedora, I had to **temporarily** set a password, for the following procedure to work.
2. Use dnf to manually install Cinnamon.
3. Power down and then cold boot.
4. From the login screen, before entering the password, set the desktop environment from gnome to gnome-classic.
5. Enter the gnome-classic desktop.
6. Power down.
7. Cold boot.
8. At the login screen, switch from gnome-classic to cinnamon.
9. Enter the cinnamon desktop environment.
10. **Then** I can remove my password via the bash command
    sudo passwd steve -d

The above procedure was found after experimental failures that involved either no password, or gnome rather than gnome-classic.  I found that **just because the login screen is indicating that Cinnamon has been chosen does not necessarily mean (at least in Fedora with Cinnamon manually dnf-installed on top) that the Cinnamon desktop will initiate.**